# python pandas.read_json() doesn't work for IG Labs REST

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read some json string into a pandas dataframe. I seem to be able to retrieve the json itself. But when I try to use a pandas dataframe to read it, it seems to fail.

Any experts have any thoughts?

```
import requests
import json
import pandas

url = 'https://demo-api.ig.com/gateway/deal'
s = requests.Session()
s.headers = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
              'Accept' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
              'VERSION' : '2',
              'X-IG-API-KEY' : 'XXX'
              }
data = { 'identifier' : 'XXX',
         'password' : 'XXX'
         }

r = s.post(url + '/session', json=data)
r.json()
```

I get the json string data below

```
> {'accountType': 'CFD',  'accountInfo': {'balance': 0,  
> 'deposit': 0.0,   'profitLoss': 0.0,   'available': 0}, 
> 'currencyIsoCode': 'GBP',  'currencySymbol': '£',  'currentAccountId':
> 'XXXX',  'lightstreamerEndpoint':
> 'https://demo-apd.marketdatasystems.com',  'accounts': [{'accountId':
> 'xxx',    'accountName': 'Demo-Spread bet',    'preferred': False,  
> 'accountType': 'SPREADBET'},   {'accountId': 'xxx',   
> 'accountName': 'Demo-CFD',    'preferred': True,    'accountType':
> 'CFD'}],  'clientId': 'xxx',  'timezoneOffset': 1, 
> 'hasActiveDemoAccounts': True,  'hasActiveLiveAccounts': True, 
> 'trailingStopsEnabled': False,  'reroutingEnvironment': None, 
> 'dealingEnabled': True}
```

However, when I try to convert r.json() into a panda, using data = pandas.read_json(r.json()); I get the error **ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type:**

Answer (score 2):

**Imports:**

```
import pandas as pd
```

**Create a main DataFrame:**

```
df_main = pd.DataFrame()
```

**Data: it's not in json format**

```
data = {'accountType': 'CFD',
        'accountInfo': {'balance': 0,
                        'deposit': 0.0,
                        'profitLoss': 0.0,
                        'available': 0},
        'currencyIsoCode': 'GBP',
        'currencySymbol': '£',
        'currentAccountId': 'XXXX',
        'lightstreamerEndpoint': 'https://demo-apd.marketdatasystems.com',
        'accounts': [{'accountId': 'xxx',
                      'accountName': 'Demo-Spread bet',
                      'preferred': False,
                      'accountType': 'SPREADBET'}, 
                     {'accountId': 'xxx',
                      'accountName': 'Demo-CFD',
                      'preferred': True,
                      'accountType': 'CFD'}],
        'clientId': 'xxx',
        'timezoneOffset': 1, 
        'hasActiveDemoAccounts': True,
        'hasActiveLiveAccounts': True, 
        'trailingStopsEnabled': False,
        'reroutingEnvironment': None, 
        'dealingEnabled': True}
```

**DataFrame.from_dict: each key is an index**

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
```

**Transpose it: each key is now a column header and the values are in rows**

```
df_trans = df.transpose()
```

**Append it to `df_main`: each record is appended to `df_main`**

```
df_main = df_main.append(df_tras, ignore_index=True)
```

---

**This is a valid json format of your data:** Paste this into a file and name the file `data.json`, then use `pd.read_json('data.json')` and you'll get the same output as `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')`.

```
{
   "data":{
      "accountType":"CFD",
      "accountInfo":{
         "balance":0,
         "deposit":0.0,
         "profitLoss":0.0,
         "available":0
      },
      "currencyIsoCode":"GBP",
      "currencySymbol":"£",
      "currentAccountId":"XXXX",
      "lightstreamerEndpoint":"https://demo-apd.marketdatasystems.com",
      "accounts":[
         {
            "accountId":"xxx",
            "accountName":"Demo-Spread bet",
            "preferred":"False",
            "accountType":"SPREADBET"
         },
         {
            "accountId":"xxx",
            "accountName":"Demo-CFD",
            "preferred":"True",
            "accountType":"CFD"
         }
      ],
      "clientId":"xxx",
      "timezoneOffset":1,
      "hasActiveDemoAccounts":"True",
      "hasActiveLiveAccounts":"True",
      "trailingStopsEnabled":"False",
      "reroutingEnvironment":"None",
      "dealingEnabled":"True"
   }
}
```